# Distinct Rows In Sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table that record events as it happens and as such could record same ID multiple times. I want to return single row for each unique RefID as 'Y' is substituted for 'N' in relevant columns. Below is a mock-up

```
    DECLARE @Ref TABLE 
    (   
      RefID        INT
     , InvoiceNo    INT 
     , InvoicedDate Date
     , CustID       INT 
     , PaidOnTime   CHAR(1)
     , Paidlate     CHAR(1)
     , PaidByCash   CHAR(1) 
     , PaidByCard   CHAR(1)
    )
   INSERT INTO @Ref VALUES
   (23,50,'22-jun-2015', 11,'Y','N','Y','N')
 , (23,50,'22-jun-2015', 11,'Y','N','N','Y')
 , (27,11,'12-Aug-2015', 11,'Y','N','N','Y')
 , (27,11,'22-Aug-2015', 11,'N','Y','N','Y')
 , (45,67,'28-jun-2015', 11,'N','Y','Y','N')
 , (45,67,'28-jun-2015', 11,'N','N','N','Y')
 , (48,51,'18-jun-2015', 11,'Y','N','Y','N') 

 SELECT * FROM @Ref --would return values like so:
```

[image]

For example, RefID of 23 should be "23,50,22/06/2015,11,Y,N,Y,Y"

Comment: Same output as input?

Comment: Have a look at group by and distinct. They should cover you.

Comment: Distinct and Group By Clauses would not handle this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group by the columns you want to be unique and use `max()` to get the highest value for every group (since `Y` is alphabetically higher than `N`)

```
SELECT RefID, InvoiceNo, InvoicedDate, CustID,
       max(PaidOnTime), max(Paidlate), max(PaidByCash), max(PaidByCard)
FROM @Ref 
GROUP BY RefID, InvoiceNo, InvoicedDate, CustID
```

Comment: Thanks Juergen for the swift response. But RefID 27 is still duplicated in the result set.

Comment: @dLight: If that is not what you want then please add the desired output to your question. What about the other columns - the date for instance. Please be more specific

Comment: @Juergen, sorry I didn't consider the date. Right answer!